# Notify user when arriving marker in the map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, geofencing

I use Geofencing to notify users when they enter a region and when they exit it. However, I need to notify them when they arrive the center of the region, is there a way to do this?

Comment: GPS is inherently noisy -- there's no way to know with certainty that someone has landed at the center of a region. Maybe consider using a region with a smaller diameter?

Comment: It's just too much if I use many regions, the max by Apple documentations is 20. Thank you.